# Cake3: How to set up belongsToMany Association with Tables in different databases?

Tags: cakephp

Working with a legacy database, I have to deal with following structure:
- database_a has a table 'Articles' 
- database_b has two tables 'Tags' and 'ArticlesTags'

I configured database_a as the 'default' connection and database_b as a 'second' connection. Then I baked models for Articles, Tags and also an ArticlesTags model. For the Tags Model and the ArticlesTags model I added '-c second' as bake option. Nevertheless the associations were only partly autodetected, therefore I had to configure them by hand: In both ArticlesTable and TagsTable I configured a belongsToMany Association to Tags resp. to Articles with the option: 'trough' => 'ArticlesTags'.
In ArticlesTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('articles');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'through' => 'ArticlesTags'
        ]);
    }
```

In TagsTable:

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tags');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
            'through' => 'ArticlesTags'
        ]);
    }

    public static function defaultConnectionName()
    {
        return 'second';
    }
```

In the ArticlesTagsTable bake did already set up two belongsTo associations to Tags and Articles. In ArticlesTagsTable and TagsTable the defaultConnection was also set correctly to 'second':

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('articles_tags');

        $this->belongsTo('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }

    public static function defaultConnectionName()
    {
        return 'second';
    }
```

Now the problem: When fetching an article with the related tags, erverythig is ok. But when I try to fetch a tag with the related articles, I get a SQL error "Table 'database_a.articles_tags' doesn't exist" which is true because table articles_tags is not in database_a but in database_b.

How can I fetch the related articles of a tag? Did I miss sth. to configure? Or could this be a bug in the ORM?

Comment: Note that the option is `through`, not `trough`. I think that what you're trying to specify there is the default anyway, so not going to make a difference here.

Comment: you're right. I corrected the spelling but the error message remains.

Comment: Are the connection parameters (host, user and password) the same for both databases?

Comment: Yes, i can fetch Tags from database_b without a problem. I don't really need the ArticlesTags-Model, but can fetch these records too. I only chose the 'through' option for setting up the association because with the 'joinTable' => 'articles_tags' option, where would I configure the connection for the joinTable?
And yes: host, user and pw are the same for both databases.

Comment: What I expect is happening here is that it's pulling Articles with one query, then joining the Tags and ArticlesTags tables in order to get the tags. That works, because Tags and ArticlesTags are in the same database. Going the other way, it pulls Tags with one query, then tries to join Articles with ArticlesTags, which fails because they are in different databases. You should be able to confirm this by enabling SQL query logging.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm not sure what the best solution is, as this isn't something I've done. From [the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations), it seems you could use `'strategy' => 'select'` on the problematic `belongsTo` association, that might be the easiest and most straight-forward.

Comment: My controller-code "$this->Tags->get($id, [ 'contain' => ['Articles']])" produces a lot of SQL where "SELECT Tags.id AS `Tags__id`, Tags.name AS `Tags__name` FROM tags Tags WHERE Tags.id = 1 LIMIT 1" and "SELECT ArticlesTags.id AS `Articles_CJoin__id`, ArticlesTags.tag_id AS `Articles_CJoin__tag_id`, ArticlesTags.article_id AS `Articles_CJoin__article_id`, Articles.id AS `Articles__id`, Articles.name AS `Articles__name` FROM articles Articles INNER JOIN articles_tags ArticlesTags ON Articles.id = (ArticlesTags.article_id) WHERE ArticlesTags.tag_id in (1)" is what you mean?

Comment: Now I changed the association in ArticlesTagsTable to "$this->belongsTo('Articles', ['foreignKey' => 'article_id','strategy' => 'select']);" but nothing changed. Should there now be three queries instead of two?

Comment: That would have been my guess, yes. Again, haven't had a need to do this, but it seemed supported by the documentation. Hopefully, the info here will help someone more knowledgeable in this area quickly solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hopefully there are other ideas. If not, I tend to file a bug report. ORM should honour the connection setting of the pivot table.